# Scala constructors using val not playing nicely with serialization framework

Tags: scala, serialization, constructor, decompiling

I'm having an issue with some Scala code and am trying to rule out a bad class design (well, constructor design) before I begin to treat it as a networking issue.

So I have a model Scala class called `Hail`:

```
class Hail(val handle : String, val message : String) extends BaseMessage {
  def this() {
    this("default_user", "default_message")
  }
}

abstract class BaseMessage extends AbstractMessage(true) {
}

// This is a 3rd party open source class written in Java
public abstract class AbstractMessage implements Message
{
    private transient boolean reliable = true;

    protected AbstractMessage()
    {
    }

    protected AbstractMessage( boolean reliable )
    {
        this.reliable = reliable; 
    }

    public Message setReliable(boolean f)
    {
        this.reliable = f;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isReliable()
    {
        return reliable;
    }
}

// This is also a 3rd party open source class written in Java
public interface Message
{
    public Message setReliable(boolean f);

    public boolean isReliable();
}
```

At runtime, instances of this class get serialized (to binary), sent over the wire to a server, where they are deserialized (back into `Hail` instances) and processed.

So I have client code that looks like this:

```
val h1 : Hail = new Hail("user1", "Hello!")
val h2 : Hail = new Hail("user2", "Aloha!")
val h3 : Hail = new Hail("user3", "Bien venu mes amigos")

client.send(h1)
client.send(h2)
client.send(h3)
```

When the server receives these messages, it prints out their handle/message combos to STDOUT. The messages I receive are as follows:

```
Server received a Hail: default_user, default_message
Server received a Hail: default_user, default_message
Server received a Hail: default_user, default_message
```

*Instead* of what I would be expecting:

```
Server received a Hail: user1, Hello!
Server received a Hail: user1, Aloha!
Server received a Hail: user3, Bien venu mes amigos
```

**Again**, this *could* be a networking/serialization/server-side issue. But before I go down that route I want to make sure my `Hail` class has been written correctly.

The serialization framework I'm using **requires** all messages (such as `Hail`) to have no-arg constructors (hence the one I provided above). So it seems to me that something is wrong with my other constructor, and perhaps the server defaults to calling the no-arg constructor because it can't use anything else.

I decompiled my `Hail` class and see the following:

```
@ScalaSignature(bytes="<lots of bytes here omitted for brevity")
public class Hail
  extends BaseMessage
{
  private final String handle;

  public String handle()
  {
    return this.handle;
  }

  public String message()
  {
    return this.message;
  }

  public Hail()
  {
    this("default_user", "default_message");
  }

  public Hail(String handle, String message) {}
}
```

Right away several things are curious/suspicious to me:

- Although I see a `private final String handle` (which is desired!), I don't see a reciprocal `private final String message` field...
- Also, the 2nd constructor (`public Hail(String handle, String message)`) is empty/undefined. **This is probably the root of my issues.**

So I ask, how can I refactor `Hail`'s source so that the following end result is bytecode that *would* decompile to:

```
@ScalaSignature(bytes="<lots of bytes here omitted for brevity")
public class Hail
  extends BaseMessage
{
  private final String handle;

  public String handle()
  {
    return this.handle;
  }

  public String message()
  {
    return this.message;
  }

  public Hail()
  {
    this("default_user", "default_message");
  }

  public Hail(String handle, String message)
  {
    this.handle = handle;
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please also show `BaseMessage`. Does it contain the `message` field?

Comment: Thanks @Thilo (+1) - I updated the question and provided the full class hierarchy. The `AbstractMessage` class and `Message` interface are from a 3rd party library.

Comment: That decompilation must be incomplete somehow. If it refers to `this.message` then that should be defined somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried printing to STDOUT before sending ? You will quickly see if your objects are created as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @CyrilleCorpet (+1) yes I print the values before sending and have **confirmed** the instances are in the correct state. The problem only occurs on the server-side when the `Hail` is deserialized.

Comment: And @Thilo I updated my question with a screenshot of the decompiler I'm using. It called [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/). Please let me know if there are any other tools/etc. I can use to aid in the diagnosis!

Comment: The jar files on client and server that have these messages are identical, right?

Comment: Yep I have a `shared` jar that both client and server use, and they use the same version of that jar!

Comment: I'd wager this is a problem of your serializer, which probably instantiate with no-arg constructor, and then changes values. But since your values are final (being `val`s, that is not possible, so they stay at their default value)

Comment: Hey! Thanks @CyrilleCorpet (+1) that was it!!! I changed `Hail` to use `var` instead of `val` for its primary constructor args and now everything is working. If you feel up to the task of putting this together in a short answer, I'll happily give you the "green check"! Thanks again!

Comment: Also now that I know the issue, I changed the title of the question to make it more searchable/helpful for people experiencing the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the serializer server-side uses the no-arg constructor, and then change the values of mutable parameters in the class.

However, scala `val`s are not mutable, so they are compiled as `final` parameters of your class, and as such cannot be mutated. So the objects are instantiated with the default values, and then keep those values, since they cannot be mutated.

I would recommend using a scala-compatible serializer, but a simpler solution is to allow the properties to be mutated by declaring them as `var`s instead of `val`s.